# How to open *.jdk file?

Tags: file

I have file which has extension JDK.
Can anyone please tell What does it mean. 
How to open it.
I have tried note pad it was showing data but with special character.
I need formatted data.

Answer (score 0):

> The Java Development Kit (JDK) is a software development environment used for developing Java applications and applets. It includes the Java Runtime Environment (JRE), an interpreter/loader (java), a compiler (javac), an archiver (jar), a documentation generator (javadoc) and other tools needed in Java development.

When you install a JDK it extracts a folder to a path and it's named as `jdk{version}`.

I'm guessing that you're using a mac because JDK's look like `jdk{version}.jdk` in macs. This can be found at `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`. However, you can open this just like another folder. But if that's not the case, you can hold `control` and click 
the file with the extension `.jdk` and select `show package contents`.

As far as using it, you usually set it up as your JDK in your IDE.

Comment: I know about Java Development Kit .this file is not Java Development Kit .its only file which contained some data.this file is used for store data.